# Formula for how many dice (with 6,8,10,or 12 sides) will show at least 4,5,6,etc.?

Tags: probability

What is the formula for figuring this out:

I have $x$ dice with $y$ sides. What is the probability that at least $j$ dice will show up with $k$ for above?

For example 3 dice with 8 sides, what is the probability that at least 2 of them show up with 4 or above? How about at least 2 of them showing 6 or above?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all fair dice, with $j \le x, 1 \le k \le y$ and also assuming $y$ faces have numbers $1$ to $y$ on them. Based on your example, I am reading it as $k$ or above.

Probability of a dice showing $k$ or above $= \frac{y-(k-1)}{y} = \frac{y-k+1}{y}$
Probability of a dice showing $ \lt k$ $= \frac{k-1}{y}$

If at least $j$ dice have to show numbers $k$ or above $ = \displaystyle \sum \limits_{i = j}^x {^xC_i} \frac{(y-k+1)^i (k-1)^{x-i}}{y^x}$

Comment: what does the "x C i" part mean?

Comment: Any $i$ dice from $x$ dice can meet the condition of $k$ or above. It is the number of ways in which $i$ dice can be chosen from $x$ dice that show $k$ or above ($x! / (i)! (x-i)!$).

Comment: thank you so much